# Dynamic where clause on model relationships on SpringBoot / Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

First of all, I am pretty new to Spring EcoSystem... still learning. So here is my question...

**Problem**

I have a table called `destinations` and `destination_translations` to store translations about destinations

```
+----+------+------------+------------+
| id | code | created_at | updated_at |
+----+------+------------+------------+
```

and my destination_translations table

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | destination_id | locale | name | created_at | updated_at     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to access all my translation using my parent model, like below. This works, but this fetches every translation that is associated with the destination_id

```java
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Table(name = "destinations", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "code"))
public class Destination extends BaseModel {

    private String code;

    private long latitude;

    private long longitude;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "destination_id")
    private List<DestinationTranslation> translations;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "model_id")
    @Where(clause = "model_namespace='App\\\\Models\\\\Destination' AND meta_type='IMAGE'")
    private List<MetaDetail> photos;

}
```

I'm getting an Accept-Header with every request, since my database has all the needed translations I need to resolve translations to what ever language that has passed to me by the client.

For example if I get a Accept-Header with `ja-jp` for a `GET` request to fetch the 1st destination then according to the accept header I should resolve all the translations for `ja-jp` only (Japanese)

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "code": "SIG",
   "translations": [
       // array of Japanese translated data
   ]
}
```

***Accept-Language should match locale of the destination_translations table***

I could write a custom query using the ***`@Query()`*** annotation but i have number of these tables which functions in the same way.

I have tried ***`@Where()`*** but it only works for static. if anyone can point on the right direction that would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hibernate filters? *A filter criteria allows you to define a restriction clause similar to the existing "where" attribute available on the class and various collection elements. These filter conditions, however, can be parameterized.* https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch19.html

Comment: Yeah, i have looked into this.. but the thing is this has be HTTP request based if i implement filters into this, which involve threading... and i believe that will be a huge implementation.